# problem during typecasting during function calling

Tags: c++, function, typecasting-operator

In the program i am converting the character datatype into integer but it is displaying the ASCII code of the character, why? what should i do to print 4 as output?

```
void fun(int x)
{
cout<<x;
}

int main()
{
char ch='4';
fun((int)ch);
return 0;
}
```

I have tried changing the parameter from 'int  x' to 'char x' and then typecasting in cout as 'cout<<(int)x;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting a `char` to `int` will do what it should, cast the stored value into an integer. When you say `char ch='4';`, the variable holds the ASCII value of `'4'`, it does not store the integer value `4`. So casting it will not give you the integer value `4`.

To get the integer value of `ch` (get `4` from `'4'`), we can subtract the integer value by '0' so that we get the actual integer value,

```cpp
void fun(int x)
{
    cout << x - '0';
}
```

Comment: The `atoi` has undefined behaviour since `&ch` is not a null-terminated string. The correct method is `ch - '0'`.

Comment: Don't use `48` - it's neither standard nor portable. Only `'0'` is guaranteed to work everywhere and forever.

Comment: @molbdnilo Noted!

Comment: The number printed will always be an integer, since the result of the subtraction is an `int`, not a `char`.